# How to Delete all the Items from SharePoint List without iteration using SharePoint Webservice

Tags: sharepoint, c#-4.0, sharepoint-2010

I wanted to delete all the Items from SharePoint List using Lists webservice,
i know we can do it by iterating all the items, my problem is that the, i have 25000 items in my list and wanted to delete it in one go, Is there any way to do this?

or is there a way to get all the attributes of List then delte the list and re-create the list with the previously saved attributes.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the way we can do it simply:

```
XmlNode listItems = SharepointUtilities.GetListItems(sharePointCredentials, sharePointCredentials.SharePointListName);
        var nodes = (from nd in listItems.ChildNodes.OfType<XmlNode>() where nd.NodeType.Equals(System.Xml.XmlNodeType.Element) select nd);
        var itemIDs = from nd in nodes.FirstOrDefault().ChildNodes.OfType<XmlNode>() where nd.NodeType.Equals(System.Xml.XmlNodeType.Element) select nd.Attributes["ows_ID"].Value;
        if (itemIDs.Count() > 0)
        {
            Lists spSrv = GetSharepointListsService(sharePointCredentials);
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            XmlElement batchElement = doc.CreateElement("Batch");
            batchElement.SetAttribute("OnError", "Continue");
            string batchCommand = "<Method ID='1' Cmd='Delete'><Field Name='ID'>";
            batchCommand += string.Join("</Field></Method><Method ID='1' Cmd='Delete'><Field Name='ID'>", itemIDs.ToArray());
            batchCommand += "</Field></Method>";
            batchElement.InnerXml = batchCommand;
            spSrv.UpdateListItems(sharePointCredentials.SharePointListName, batchElement);

        }
```

Answer (score 2):

You could save the list as a template (List Settings -> Save list as template), then delete the list, then create a new list based on the template that you saved.

Comment: Smart idea, really :)
Just make sure not to check the include content checkbox when creating the template.

Comment: then i have to save: ListName, all the columnNames with its type and length?, any thing else i have to save.

Comment: @KhuzemaKamaal - I'm not sure what you mean. You don't manually have to save anything. Once you save your current list as a template each new list you create based on the saved template will be indentical to the current list without the content (same columns, same field definitions, same column calculations, etc...)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [UpdateListItems](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.lists.updatelistitems%28v=office.12%29.aspx) method of the Lists web service, however it is still going to take a long time to delete all items at once.
Try the following snippet -

```
var batch = new StringBuilder();
batch.Append("<Batch OnError='Continue' ListVersion='1' ListName='{GUID}'>");

string itemTemplate = "<Method ID='1' Cmd='Delete'><Field Name='ID'>{0}</Field></Method>";

for (int i = 0; i < 300000; i++)
    batch.Append(string.Format(itemTemplate, i));

batch.Append("</Batch>");

//query Lists service
```

This code assumes that your item's ID range is from 0 to 300000 - this will be your only option without iterating 
all items (and getting their ID). However, with this much items even the StringBuilder will run into performance
problems, not to mention SharePoint.

Your best bet is to delete the site and re-create it like pmartin suggested it.

Answer (score 0):

Open the list in DataSheetView, select all records (ctrl+A) and Delete all records.
This is the shortest solution.